# Find $b$ such that biquadratic equation $x^4+bx^2+1=0$ has no real solutions

Tags: polynomials

Find Values of b , such that the biquadratic has no real solutions
$$x^4+bx^2+1=0$$

My try :

Let $t=x^2$. Then the biquadratic reduces to

$$t^2+bt+1=0$$

Now, $d=b^2-4$. The equation has no solutions when $d<0$. Thus, $b^2-4<0$ gives us $b\in(-2,2)$

The answer is $b>-2$ instead. Could someone explain where i'am going wrong ?

Comment: Hint: what would the solutions be for $b=3$ ?

Comment: Ohk thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express $b$ in terms of $x$ and then examine its range,

$$b=-\frac{x^4+1}{x^2} =-\left(x-\frac1{x}\right)^2-2$$

which indicates that $b\le -2$ for all real $x$. Thus, $b>-2$

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're simply not finished.  What you did so far is find all $b$ so that
\begin{equation}\tag{$*$}t^2+bt+1=0\end{equation} has no real solutions in $t$.  But notice that even if
\begin{equation}\tag{$**$}x^4+bx^2+1=0\end{equation}
has no real solution $(*)$ still might.  Due to $t=x^2$, this happens precisely when $t<0$.  In particular, no real solutions to $(**)$ exist so long as
$$
0>\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4}}{2}\;\text{  or }\;0>\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4}}{2}.
$$
where $|b|\geqslant 2$.  Each of these inequalities are equivalent to $b\geqslant 2$.

Answer (score 0):

The extrema of the function are given by

$$4x^3+2bx=0$$ or

$$x=0\lor 2x^2=-b.$$

We always have $f(0)=1$ and when $b<0$, $f\left(\pm\sqrt{-\dfrac b2}\right)=-\dfrac{b^2}4+1$.

The only way to have real roots is when there is a change of sign between a minimum and a maximum, which requires $b<0$ and $|b|\ge2$.

[image]

Comment: @Ishaan: are you sure that my conclusion is different ?

Comment: No sorry you are right !